# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) issue when making img request

Tags: django, cookies, http-headers, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am currently trying to implement this solution [here](https://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains/). The solution seems pretty simple and possible since I am the owner of both of the hosts. On mysite1.com I have added the following `img` tag.

```
<img src="//mysite1.com.com/cookie_set/" style="display:none;">
```

On my site2.com (django), I have a view like so:

```
def cookie_set(request):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.set_cookie('my_cookie', value='awesome')
    return response
```

When I release this code live. I get the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.mysite2.com/cookie_set/ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/121212121221 for more details.
```

I thought that maybe if I just added `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` in my view this might fix things, but according the docs here: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers, there's one more consideration:

> For example, it will block a cross-origin text/html response requested from a  or  tag, replacing it with an empty response instead.

Are my assumptions correct? After adding the correct headers should I just change the content-type to something other than `text/html`?

Ultimately, my final goal is I would like to set a cookie for a different domain that I have control of (ideally without a redirect).

Comment: Might be an option for you to set the cookie via `xhr` using `withCredentials`. See https://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request

Answer (score 1):

Best solution: use a different tag for this. (i.e. iframe).

The point behind CORB is to prevent certain tags from being used for XSSI data injection So img tags requests should not return text/html, application/json, or xml content types.

So unless the call to img tag really is for capturing the request itself (for referrer tracking, for example), then you get much more versatility by executing in an iframe anyway (like for SSO-redirection workflows).

See also: [Setting third party cookie by using 1x1 <img> tag - Javascript doesn't drop cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415860/setting-third-party-cookie-by-using-1x1-img-tag-javascript-doesnt-drop-cook)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for image files by updating the `Content-Type` metadata under Properties in S3 - `image/jpeg` for JPEG files and `image/png` for PNG files.

My application uploads image files via [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) and it seems it applies `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. It has a [contentType option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3#setting-custom-content-type) with content-type auto-detect feature - this should prevent improper headers and fix the CORB issue.

It seems the latest Chrome 76 version update includes listening to remote file URL headers, specifically `Content-Type`. CORB was not an issue for other browsers such as Firefox, Safari, and in-app browsers e.g. Instagram.